# How to use a Data Array within a Chart JS dataset?

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I have the following JSON, that I want to insert a chart using Chart JS:

```
{"Results":[{"Data":"25/02/2021","Valor":18},{"Data":"24/02/2021","Valor":2993},{"Data":"23/02/2021","Valor":1936},{"Data":"22/02/2021","Valor":1844},{"Data":"21/02/2021","Valor":1114},{"Data":"20/02/2021","Valor":1060},{"Data":"19/02/2021","Valor":1134}]}
```

And I created a function to load this JSON into an Array:

```
function ShowData(jsonObj) {
  var bases = jsonObj['Results'];
  var Date = [];
  var Val = [];

  for (var i = bases.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {

    Date.push([bases[i].Data]);

    Val.push([bases[i].Valor]);
  }
}
```

When I load this Array into the Chart, As below:

```
var chartGraph = new Chart(ctx,{
        type:'line',
        data:{
            labels: Date,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Lbl Name",
                    data: Val,
                    borderWidth: 6,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(77,166,253, 0.85)',
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                fontSize: 20,
                text: 'Chart Name'
            },

            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
                labels: {
                        fontColor: '#666'
                    }
            }
        }
    })
```

No information on "datasets" appears to me, only the "label", what is the mistake I am making?

[Graphic Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Bz4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to split `series` and `data`, something like:

```
function splitData(type) {
  return json.Results.map(v => v[type]);
}

// your Chart.js config
data: {
 labels: splitData('Date'),
 datasets: [
   {
     // ...otherProps,
     data: splitData('Valor')
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand how to make this "split" function, it's from Array or Json, could you explain it to me?

Comment: Your data is an object containing an unique key called `Results`, which is an Array, so you will be able to `map` it to get the desired series/data values for the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `Date` as variable name since its a build in class. Also from my testing couldnt reference the vars inside the function. But the real problem with your code is that you push an array to the `val` array. This made it an array containing arrays. This is not supported. If you change your code to the sample below it will work

```
let date = [];
let val = [];

function ShowData(jsonObj) {
  var bases = jsonObj['Results'];
  date = [];
  val = [];

  for (var i = bases.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {

    date.push(bases[i].Data);

    val.push(bases[i].Valor);
  }
}

var chartGraph = new Chart(ctx,{
        type:'line',
        data:{
            labels: Date,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Lbl Name",
                    data: Val,
                    borderWidth: 6,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(77,166,253, 0.85)',
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                fontSize: 20,
                text: 'Chart Name'
            },

            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
                labels: {
                        fontColor: '#666'
                    }
            }
        }
    })
```